# Error when pushing certain commits to GitHub: RPC failed; curl 55 LibreSSL SSL_read: LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404C3FC:SSL

Tags: github, gnupg

Weird issue when pushing commits to the origin. When I push a small change (just altering one or two lines) I can push no problem, but when rebuilding the source (which creates more significant changes ~30MB) I get the following error after running `git push`

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 LibreSSL SSL_read: LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404C3FC:SSL routines:ST_OK:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Weirdly, this problem only started occuring after I added my GPG signature to commits. Coincidence?

I tried using the `git config` command to expand the size of the buffer to check it wasn't just the size of the commit, but I can't figure out why it started after adding GPG signing, but also only occurs on larger commits.